# Docker build freezes installing packages from apt

Tags: build, docker, apt-get

I have a dockerfile which needs installing some 720mb worth of packages from apt.

```
run DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y python-pip python-dev\
    supervisor mercurial subversion buildbot buildbot-slave subversion doxygen\
    cmake cloc build-essential valgrind cccc scons g++ cppcheck qt4-dev-tools\
    wget lcov graphviz
```

The build runs up to almost half of the packages requested, then it just hangs idle there.

Is there a way to know for sure if the process has halted or if it's just idle waiting for the network or something along those lines?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check which process is running using e.g. `ps faux | less`. Scroll down to find the `lxc-start` process corresponding to your container, and see what is running under it (the `f` flag triggers a forest display which should show in a pretty obvious way which processes belong to the container).

Then, you can use `strace -fp <pid>` to attach to the last running process in that container and see what it is doing.

Last but not least, you can try to break down the command in 2 or 3 phases. In the (unlikely) case where the problem would come from a package prompting you for input (which shouldn't happen since you specified the `noninteractive` front-end, but who knows) that will help to single it out.

Comment: Thank you for the tips. I've checked and the process was idle due to the crappy internet connection we have here...

Answer (score 2):

Most of the time it's a network issue. Do you use a proxy on your host?